# Collecting URLs from a form and putting them into array but ignore empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have this form where a user can enter URLs i want ti put them all into an array but if its empty i don't want it in the array.

I found another answer on stackoverflow and tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

**if i enter the following into my form**

```
http://URL1.com
http://URL2.com

http://URL3.com

http://URL4.com

http://URL5.com
```

**This is the PHP Code:**

```
$seperateURLs = preg_split('/\n/', $_POST['uploadedURLS']);


foreach($seperateURLs as $key => $URL) {
    if($URL == "") 
        { 
            unset($seperateURLs[$key]); 
        }
}
$allURLs = array_values($seperateURLs);

print_r($allURLs);
```

**This is what is returned:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://URL1.com
    [1] => http://URL2.com
    [2] => 
    [3] => http://URL3.com
    [4] => 
    [5] => http://URL4.com
    [6] => 
    [7] => http://URL5.com
)
```

Comment: Either use `trim($URL)` when comparing with empty string `""` or you can use `array_filter(array_values($seperateURLs))`

Comment: i added trim($URL) and array_filter(array_values($seperateURLs))  but i still have the gaps.

Comment: How did you add `trim($URL)`? It should be `if (trim($URL) == "")`

Comment: Why use `preg_split` instad of `explode`? You're not using any kind of pattern, just a constant string.

Comment: Could you show what `var_dump($separatURLS)` prints?

Comment: Ah i added the trim in wrong place. Its working thanks Barmar and Rahil Wazir its working now!

Answer (score 0):

I would add the URLs to a new array, and make sure that they are properly trimmed in the process:

```
$seperateURLs = preg_split('/\n/', $_POST['uploadedURLS']);
$allURLs = array ();

foreach($seperateURLs as $key => $URL) {
  $u = trim($URL);
  if($u) !== "") {
    $allURLs[] = $u;
  }
}

print_r($allURLs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the null values with **[preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)** with argument `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`

```
$seperateURLs = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $_POST['uploadedURLS'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($seperateURLs);
```